# Use apt get install without inserting the DVD?

Tags: debian

I installed Debian 7 using a DVD version, so every time I'm trying to install something using apt-get, the system ask me to mount the DVD. Is there a way to avoid that (inserting every time the dvd).

Comment: Editing Repositories lists doesn't help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could copy the DVD to an ISO and then mount it permanently as a filesystem on the machine (and point apt at it, by modifying `/etc/apt/sources.list`).  However, assuming the machine has an Internet connection, you could just switch to using the online repositories.

Details are [here](http://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList).

But here's an example,

Edit /etc/apt/sources.list and replace the contents with this (this works for Wheezy or Debian 7, for earlier or later versions, check the link above),

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

Then run `apt-get update` to refresh the package details.

Comment: I tied :#root:  "gedit /etc/ ... " cant access the file, i tried too, chmod 777 /etc .." but no sccess, im wondering how is possible to access that file !

Comment: So your question is wrong, your question needs to be 'I tried to edit /etc/apt/sources.list but can't'.  You really need to make sure you've given everyone all the info before asking questions.

Comment: I can access it now. do i have to reaplace all the content  of the file, or just add lines in the end ?

Comment: Replace all of it, with what I have provided above.

Comment: Is there a command line option to do it? I'm literally trying to install `emacs`, so I don't have a text editor at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Just a caveat here.

If you're dealing with some problem where you've got incorrect settings in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, e.g. a disk is expected, it's probably a good idea to to rewrite the file from scratch.

To do this for Debian I just used https://debgen.simplylinux.ch/ to generate the file.

Initially I just tried just removing the reference from `sources.list` as recommended, but then I subsequently got other errors when trying to update packages, such as

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution...`
```

or

```
git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
```

These came up for me because my version of `sources.list`
 didn't point to the package sources I needed, however regenerating `sources.list` fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I needed some insight so after reading these posts I used nano to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, i.e.

```
# nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Once in the file, the first source was the CD pointer so all I had to do was to comment that line out with the `#` character and all was fixed. I'm now getting the packages from the repositories listed in the `sources.list` file.

Thanks for the help.